# UITableViewCell custom label is not getting value

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm currently creating a tableview with data from server. I have made it before, i copied over the code from the other files, but for some reason it's very strange. When i run the app, the tableview is empty and I found out that The cell.price.text is not updating, even though I hardcode it as @"123", cell.price.text is still showing null in NSLog.

I'm sure all these three method are called, because I put nslog in each of them

```
//TableView Setting
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSLog(@"Countdata %i",countdata);
    return countdata;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ShopTableViewCell";

    ShopTableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                                     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ShopTableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        NSLog(@"hi");
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.price.text = [self.gprice objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSLog(@"Good,%@",[self.gprice objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]);
    NSLog(@"text,%@",cell.price.text);

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Do not post code as an image. Update your question by copying and pasting the actual code into your question (and please ensure it is formatted properly).

Comment: is your cellForRow method being called? if not, you are not implementing the tableview's data source or returning 0 as number of row for that section.

Comment: @rmaddy Hi, sorry I'm new to stackoverflow, How do I update my question? Thanks

Comment: You click the Edit link under your question.

Comment: @Lucho Hi, i have updated my answer with more code. I'm sure cellforrow is called, as you can see i put nslog before return cell;

Comment: see if you are dequeueing correctly the cell, print it's frame to check everything  is ok. Maybe setting the height of the row helps.

Comment: so you are getting value for `Good` and `text` nslog which you written just before return cell ?

Comment: @Pyro I get "Good, (null)". I'm just nslog good so i konw which nslog it is since i have a lot of nslog in my program

Comment: @Lucho One thing that really confuse me, cause I tried "cell.textlabel.text" (which is the default label for cell), and they show probably

Comment: if you are getting null in the nslog, as you are not getting value text field is not updating, also looks like you are passing two different objects in `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` generally they are the same to match the data with no of rows

Comment: Yeah, my problem was that the label.text is not updating, keep showing null. I couldn't understand where the problem is, cause I did it the same way in the other page, and they work perfectly

Comment: Make sure, you have allocated and initialized your `NSArray`/`NSMutableArray`

Comment: @pingping check the `self.gprice` value in this controller and previous viewcontroller there should be some difference between them in data